# Ajax post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

Try get data from server

```
<html>
    <header>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </header>
        <body>

        <div id="result">Тут будет ответ от сервера</div><br /><br />


        <script>
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://139.196.141.166:8084/course/income/outline",
        type: "POST",

        data: {},
        success:function (data) {//возвращаемый результат от сервера
                console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
        }

        });


    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

But, my console says that : Object {message: "no header", code: 500}
When I set header by this: header:   X-Authenticated-Userid:15000500000@1 - this give me my backend developer
Add to code  `headers: { 'X-Authenticated-Userid': '15000500000@1' },`

I get error Object {message: "Bad request, http code: 0, error message: ", code: 500}

May be I do something wrong ?

Comment: `500` is an internal server error. You need to look at your server side error logs.

Comment: you need to have CORS enable

Comment: Why are you using `POST` when there is no data! Use `GET` instead

Comment: When I use GET, server return's ne Method not allowed, I Have this request Request { "secure": { }, "extra": { }, "body": { } }

Answer (score 0):

Empty "POST" data. if you are trying to "GET" the data from database it's advisable to use "GET" instead of "POST"

Comment: When I use GET, server return's ne Method not allowed, I Have this request Request
{
    "secure": {
    },
    "extra": {
    },
    "body": {
    }
}

Comment: JQuery.ajax() defaults to GET so no need to specify type.

Comment: type: "POST", - I do this